# Can't Add Subdocument Field to Mongodb Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a nodejs app in express using mongodb. I was having trouble with the nested schema. For some reason when I look up objects in the collection through the terminal by using db.play.find().pretty(), the titlepage field does not even show up as a field. I don't understand why, because I feel like I am creating the subdocument the right way.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var TitlePage = new mongoose.Schema({
    chair: String,
    director: String, 
    author: String
});
var PlaySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String, 
    titlepage: TitlePage
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('play', PlaySchema);
```

Comment: What version of mongoose?

Comment: Code looks fine. Post example of document + subdocument creation.

Answer (score 0):

try creating two different Schema and referencing it.

say save it as title.js

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var TitlePage = new mongoose.Schema({
        chair: String,
        director: String, 
        author: String
    });
    module.exports = mongoose.model('titlePage', TitlePage);
```

say save it as play.js

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var title = require('./title');
    var PlaySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String, 
        titlepage: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'titlePage',
    });
    module.exports = mongoose.model('play', PlaySchema);
```

when you add the id of the title you are referencing the whole document of the title page.
This will be stored as id, if you want to show all the fields of title you will have to populate it.

Suppose you are using find method, the document you will receive will be

```
{
 name:'abc',
  titlepage: here mongoid will come
 }
```

but when you populate using find().populate([{ path: 'titlepage' }]) the response will be

```
{
 name: 'abc',
 titlePage: {
    chair: 'pqr',
    director: 'xyz',
    author: 'lmn'
             }
 }
```